# Specify type of Date field

Tags: vapor

In my `PostgreSQLModel` vapor class I'm using a simple `Migration` extension to create the database table.

```swift
extension Order: Migration {
    static func prepare(on connection: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Database.create(self, on: connection) { builder in
            try addProperties(to: builder)
            try builder.addReference(from: \.stationID, to: \Station.id)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is my `Date` fields are being created as `timestamp without time zone` whereas what I really want is just `date`.  How do I specify this?  Do I have to skip the `addProperties` and manually call `addField` on the builder myself for each column?

Comment: Why do you need to implement the `prepare` method? Usually that is implemented for you. If you really need to implement the method yourself, then yes, you need to call `addField` for every property.

Comment: As I stated, I want the field in the database to be a `date` field, and that's not what Vapor creates it as.  If there's a better way to do that than the prepare method, I'm all ears.

Comment: So you want `date` instead of `datetime`?

Comment: That's correct.  Also, it doesn't create the foreign keys by default so I was adding those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way, but I ended up doing this:

```swift
extension Order: Migration {
    static func prepare(on connection: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return Database.create(self, on: connection) { builder in
            try addProperties(to: builder)
            try builder.addReference(from: \.stationID, to: \Station.id)

            builder.schema.addFields = builder.schema.addFields.map {
                guard $0.type.type == .timestamp else { return $0 }

                let defaultValue = $0.name == CodingKeys.created.rawValue ? "now()" : nil
                let type = PostgreSQLColumn(type: .date, default: defaultValue)

                return SchemaField<PostgreSQLDatabase>(name: $0.name, type: type, isOptional: $0.isOptional)
            }
        }
    }
}
```